# Python writes into csv file, incorrectly

Tags: python, csv

I tried my code in Mac, and it is ok, but in windows, python does not write my list correctly into a CSV file, and some data is written in different rows while it should be written in the same row.

```
personel = [firstname, lastname, detail]
with open("hr.csv", "a", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(personel)
```

Comment: try without specifying newline character as ''

Comment: @EnterSB what do you mean ?

Comment: Can you post what your CSV is getting? I am not finding a problem with my CSV in my test code.

Comment: try specifying newline to be e.g. `\r\n` instead of leaving it empty.
also, which version of python are you using?

Comment: We need a sample of the data your variables have, otherwise we're not going to be very useful to you here...

Comment: As I checked some strings have carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test program with your code (on Windows 10) and didn't find a problem with the CSV output. Run this on your machine and see what happens.

This is the test output (it consists of random letters):

```
fziziszaoq,gxlcgmncdn,bjehjbcjgq
lrzzbujdru,bxxqkavqro,mktmygqmrc
mauzgqkgqw,uijnzavbyi,jhjqxkbran
oplrispslo,irvkjgcimm,kjbfbpilmi
regaajxhdf,wwtyyspuoi,icmrcjwswx
```

This is the test code:

```
import csv
import random
import string

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

x = 0
while(x < 5):
    personel = [randomString(), randomString(), randomString()]
    with open("hr.csv", "a", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(personel)
    x = x + 1
```

My suspicion is that your inputs contain newlines. Check that there are not stray newline characters in `firstname`, `lastname`, or  `detail.`